# Explain why `position_dodge(width=0.9)` centers the errorbar?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's code taken straight out of [ggplot2 documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_errorbar.html)

```
df <- data.frame(
  trt = factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2)),
  resp = c(1, 5, 3, 4),
  group = factor(c(1, 2, 1, 2)),
  se = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2)
)
df2 <- df[c(1,3),]

# Define the top and bottom of the errorbars
limits <- aes(ymax = resp + se, ymin=resp - se)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(fill=group, y=resp, x=trt))
p + geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
# Because the bars and errorbars have different widths
# we need to specify how wide the objects we are dodging are
dodge <- position_dodge(width=0.9)
p + geom_bar(position=dodge) + geom_errorbar(limits, position=dodge, width=0.25)
```

I don't understand why the `position_dodge(width=0.9)`, especially the `0.9`? How to come up with that number?

Answer (score 2):

```
# we need to specify how wide the objects we are dodging are
```

I am pretty sure 0.9 is the default width for geom_bar.

If you redo the example with geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", width=0.5) you have to change dodge to 0.5 to have it look nice.